# NSRegularExpression not working properly

Tags: ios, crash, nsstring, nsregularexpression

Hi i'm having problems where if in the string the there isn't a phone number and the NSRegularExpression cant find anything the app crashes but when it does find the phone number it in the string its works fine with no problems. How can i stop it from crashing.

```
NSRegularExpression *phoneexpression = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"\\d{4}-\\d{4}"options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:NULL];
NSString *phString = TextString;
NSString *PH = [phString substringWithRange:[phoneexpression rangeOfFirstMatchInString:phString options:NSMatchingCompleted range:NSMakeRange(0, [phString length])]];
```

I think this is the problem

```
NSString *PH = [phString substringWithRange:[phoneexpression rangeOfFirstMatchInString:phString options:NSMatchingCompleted range:NSMakeRange(0, [phString length])]];
```

Comment: Did you try change `NULL` to `&error`? show the error message please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you get a NSRangeException.

Try it this way:

```
NSString *PH = nil;
NSRegularExpression *phoneexpression = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"\\d{4}-\\d{4}"options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:NULL];
NSString *phString = TextString;
NSRange rg = [phoneexpression rangeOfFirstMatchInString:phString options:NSMatchingCompleted range:NSMakeRange(0, [phString length])];

if(rg.location != NSNotFound)
    PH = [phString substringWithRange:rg];
```

It is important that you check the returned range before passing it to substringWithRange. 
See this reference for more information: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/substringWithRange:

**EDIT:**
Also check that the returned range from rangeOfFirstMatchInString does not violate the boundary limitations documented in the reference:

> Raises an NSRangeException if **(aRange.location - 1)** or
>   **(aRange.location + aRange.length - 1)** lies beyond the end of the
>   receiver.